# Creating an index on shadow property

Tags: asp.net-core, indexing, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I am implementing a model containing a number of owned types and need to create indexes on properties of the owned types. As I understand I cannot create the indexes directly in Fluent API using `builder.HasIndex(entity => entity.location.geo);` but instead I should use a Shadow Property and create the index on this. I think I have implemented the Shadow Property (Geo) correctly, but the indexer doesn't work. Please help.

I'm using .NET5

Here is my model (simplified for readability)

```
public class Meeting
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public Point Geo { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration class:

```
public class MeetingConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Meeting>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Meeting> builder)
    {
        builder
            .ToTable("Meetings")
            .HasKey(c => c.Id);

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Id)
            .HasColumnType("bigint")
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasComment("Unique ID of the Meeting");

        builder
            .Property(c => c.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(127)")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasComment("Name of the Meeting");

        builder
            .Property(c => c.StartDate)
            .HasColumnType("date")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasComment("First date of the Meeting");

        // Configure Location owned entity
        builder
            .OwnsOne(p => p.Location, location =>
            {
                location
                    .Property(p => p.Name)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(127)")
                    .IsRequired(false)
                    .HasComment("Optional: Name of the Location");

                location
                    .Property(p => p.Geo)
                    .HasColumnType("geography (point)")
                    .IsRequired(false)
                    .HasComment("Optional: GPS Coordinates of the Location");
            });

        // Create Shadow properties for use in indexes
        builder
            .Property<Point>("Geo");
        builder
            .IndexerProperty<Point>("Geo");

        // Create Indexes
        builder
            .HasIndex(entity => new
            {
                entity.Name,
                entity.StartDate
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: so what do you mean by `the indexer doesn't work`? there is not any index created for `Geo` or there is some error? BTW, if possible, you should talk a little bit about your want more specifically so the others can easily track it and jump to the code with ease. The commented text (in the code section) is not very highly visible so it's harder to understand your issue.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11336 The last comment by EF Core dev team member is *"Note that this issue has an easy workaround - simply create the index in your migration - which means we generally don't consider this to be extremely high priority."*

Comment: I don't think there is any involvement between `IndexerProperty` and `indexed column`. The `IndexerProperty` just adds the property to the entity class to some underlying dictionary so later you can access that property via its name like an indexer (`this[property_name]`). If you want to index a column, just use `HasIndex("Geo")` which will index the column `Geo` (mapped to the corresponding shadow property).

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense.
I got errors while adding the migration, but after applying `HasIndex("Geo")` the error is gone.
I still have a few other bugs to fix before I can tell if this works, but I'll get back